# AutoMapper doesn't work at design time when using Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, automapper, caliburn.micro, design-time

#### Background

I am building user interface for existing CLI application using WPF and Caliburn.Micro. Since I am provided with a bunch of DTO objects I am using AutoMapper to pass data to models that support PropertyChanged notification (using PropertyChangedBase from Caliburn.Micro).

I setting up AutoMapper inside the [Bootstrapper#Configure](https://github.com/ProfileRedacted/CaliburnAutoMapperBug/blob/master/CaliburnAutoMapperBug/AppBootstrapper.cs#L29) method like this:

```
Mapper.Initialize(
    config => config.CreateMap<ModelA, ModelB>()
);
```

And am using it like this in my [ViewModel](https://github.com/ProfileRedacted/CaliburnAutoMapperBug/blob/master/CaliburnAutoMapperBug/ViewModels/ShellViewModel.cs):

```
private static ModelA[] source = new[] {
    new ModelA {
        Name = "foo"
    },
    new ModelA {
        Name = "bar"
    }
};

public BindableCollection<ModelB> Items { get; } = new BindableCollection<ModelB>(
    Mapper.Map<ModelA[], IEnumerable<ModelB>>(source)
);
```

#### Problem description

The problem is that when I am using [Design Time support](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/design-time) for Caliburn.Micro, the DataMapper only works when you start up the Visual Studio.

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CaliburnAutoMapperBug.ViewModels"
xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro.Platform"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:ShellViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
cal:Bind.AtDesignTime="True">
```

When you change any value in the ViewModel, the change isn't projected into the designer and after you run the application at last once the designer throws an error (image) and stops rendering, but everything works at run-time.

#### Image

[image]

#### How to replicate

1. Clone [problem example](https://github.com/ProfileRedacted/CaliburnAutoMapperBug) repository
2. Open the solution
3. Open Views/ShellView.xaml in designer
4. At this point the designer should work fine and show 3 items in StackPanel
5. Open ViewModels/ShellViewModel.cs
6. Make any changes to source array (change name, remove or add item)
7. Run the application, you should see the changes you make
8. Go back to designer for Views/ShellView.xaml
9. The designer will show a error at line 10: "Unmapped members were found..."

Comment: That's because AM is not initialized in that case, the default for CreateMissingTypeMaps is true, so it created a map for you, but that default map cannot work because IsNotifying cannot be mapped.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, that actually makes sense. Do you know where I should initialize the AutoMapper, so it would work at design time? I have tried to initialize it inside [BootstrapperBase#StartDesignTime()](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/blob/336e9506c0019fc5ea346aa14c4743622e42d45f/src/Caliburn.Micro.Platform/Bootstrapper.cs#L73) method, but that didn't work.

Comment: I don't know about that, but what you can do is move to the instance based API. And then you can inject IMapper or do it manually with Lazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't solved the problem with design time completely, but switching to instance based AutoMapper configuration as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51876662/automapper-doesnt-work-at-design-time-when-using-caliburn-micro#comment90730330_51876662) resolved the exception.

```
protected override void Configure() {
    container = new SimpleContainer();
    container.Singleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>();
    container.Singleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();
    container.PerRequest<IShell, ShellViewModel>();

    MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
        cfg.CreateMap<Core.ProjectDto, Models.Panel.Project>();
    });

    container.RegisterInstance(
        typeof(IMapper),
        "automapper",
        config.CreateMapper()
    );
}
```